# dateBySettingUnit method of NSCalendar returns not obvious result

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

My problem is solved by NSDateComponents, but I want to understand why this method works so

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"today is: %@", today);

NSDate *dayChanged = [calendar dateBySettingUnit:(NSCalendarUnitDay)
                                           value:10
                                          ofDate:today
                                         options:0];
NSLog(@"dayChanged is: %@", dayChanged);

NSDate *monthChanged = [calendar dateBySettingUnit:(NSCalendarUnitMonth)
                                             value:5
                                            ofDate:today
                                           options:0];
NSLog(@"monthChanged is: %@", monthChanged);
```

result is:

```
today is: 2016-09-30 06:40:36 +0000
dayChanged is: 2016-10-10 00:00:00 +0000
monthChanged is: 2017-05-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Why `dateBySettingUnit` increments next larger unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the observation, [dateBySettingUnit does not return past date](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12048)

So for a quick test setting using `dateBySettingUnit` for future dates works as expected, see below code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"today is: %@", today);

NSDate *dayChanged = [calendar dateBySettingUnit:(NSCalendarUnitDay)
                                           value:31
                                          ofDate:today
                                         options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
NSLog(@"dayChanged is: %@", dayChanged);

NSDate *monthChanged = [calendar dateBySettingUnit:(NSCalendarUnitMonth)
                                             value:12
                                            ofDate:dayChanged
                                           options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
NSLog(@"monthChanged is: %@", monthChanged);
```

Log:

```
2016-09-30 12:58:30.506 TestRegex[3785:72957] today is: 2016-09-30 07:58:30 +0000
2016-09-30 12:58:30.508 TestRegex[3785:72957] dayChanged is: 2016-09-30 19:00:00 +0000
2016-09-30 12:58:30.509 TestRegex[3785:72957] monthChanged is: 2016-11-30 19:00:00 +0000
```

You can try the extension for NSCalendar mentioned in the answer of the link which actually calculates the offset or you can use `NSDateComponents`
solution:

```
 NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:today];
[comps setCalendar:calendar];
[comps setDay:5];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I understood - only "future dates". Thanks you for the answer

Comment: i get the error: 'Exactly one option from the set {NSCalendarMatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits, NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits, NSCalendarMatchNextTime} must be specified.' when using only NSCalendarWrapComponents

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the behaviour of `dateBySettingUnit` can be "unexpected" since all components are actually bound together. According to the `NSCalendar` header file documentation (emphasis mine):

> The specific behaviors here are as yet unspecified; for example, if I
>   change the weekday to Thursday, does that move forward to the next,
>   backward to the previous, or to the nearest Thursday?  A likely rule
>   is that **the algorithm will try to produce a result which is in the
>   next-larger unit** to the one given (there's a table of this mapping at
>   the top of this document).  So for the "set to Thursday" example, find
>   the Thursday in the Week in which the given date resides (which could
>   be a forwards or backwards move, and not necessarily the nearest
>   Thursday).  For forwards or backwards behavior, one can use the
>   -nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options: method above.

So, depending on your needs, using the `nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:` could be more suitable.

Comment: I checked `nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:` with different options `{NSCalendarMatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits, NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits, NSCalendarMatchNextTime}`. For `matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay` it increments month